# How does showing $\varphi \circ \iota_{\mathbb S^1}$ homotopic to $\mathrm{Id}_{\mathbb S^1}$ give us a contradiction to $f$ has no fixed points?

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, fixed-point-theorems

I am trying to prove the $2$-dimensional version Brouwer's fixed point theorem.

If $f: \overline{\mathbb B^2} \to \overline{\mathbb B^2}$ is continuous and has no fixed point, and we define $\varphi: \overline{\mathbb B^2} \to \mathbb S^1$ by $\varphi(x)=\frac{x-f(x)}{|x-f(x)|}$, how does showing that $\varphi \circ \iota_{\mathbb S^1}$ is homotopic to $\mathrm{Id}_{\mathbb S^1}$ give us a contradiction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\overline{\mathbb B^2}$ is contractible, $\varphi$ is nullhomotopic, and hence so is $\varphi \circ \iota_{\mathbb S^1}$.  But $\mathrm{Id}_{\mathbb S^1}$ is not nullhomotopic, so this is a contradiction.

Comment: How is $\varphi$ nullhomotopic if it is a map going into $\mathbb S^1$? We know $\mathbb S^1$ is not contractible.

Comment: Any map with a contractible domain or codomain is nullhomotopic.  You only need either one or the other to be contractible, not both.

Comment: Can you explain the reasoning behind that? I don't think I've seen it before.

Comment: I know if we have $\varphi: \overline{\mathbb B^2} \to \mathbb S^1$, then $\varphi_*: \pi_1(\overline{\mathbb B^2}) \to \pi_1(\mathbb S^1)$ must be injective since $\pi_1(\overline{\mathbb B^2})$ is trivial.

Comment: If $X$ is contractible, then the identity $id_X:X\to X$ is homotopic to a constant map $c$.  So for any map $f:X\to Y$, $f\circ id_X=f$ is homotopic to $f\circ c$, which is a constant map.

Comment: Got it. Now if $\varphi$ is homotopic to $c$, then $\varphi \circ \iota$ is homotopic to $c \circ \iota =c$? Is this how you obtained that $\varphi \circ \iota$ is nullhomotopic? Or a different way?

Comment: Right.  Any composition with a constant map is constant, so any composition with a nullhomotopic map is nullhomotopic.